# Difficulty throwing NoSuchElementException in Java

Tags: java, exception

this is my first attempt to a code doubly linked  program in java:

This is my implementation of getting an iterator to getall items in the doubly linkedlist

```
public Object next()  {
    if(list.getSize()==0){
     throw new NoSuchElementException();

    }else{ 
        current=current.getNext();
        return current.getItem();
    } 
}
```

Please dont laugh at me but whatever I try I am getting

> Cannot find symbol : symbol class: NoSuchElementException

I tried creating a class NoSuchElementException.java which extends Exception

Then I get

> unreported exception NoSuchElementException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown
>            throw new NoSuchElementException();

I tried changing code to :

```
public Object next() throws NoSuchElementException {
```

Then I get

> next() in ElementsIterator cannot implement next() in
>   java.util.Iterator; overridden method does not throw
>   NoSuchElementException

Can anybody point to where I got wrong. If this is not sufficient info to resolve this issue, please do tell me.

Comment: Since [`NoSuchElementException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) already exists, you shouldn't need to create a new file to contain a definition of it. I _think_ if you `import java.util.*;` (and remove your new file), you can use the `NoSuchElementException` already provided by the language. But it's been years since I've really done Java, so hopefully a better answer will come along soon.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you suggested I added import java.util.* and removed NoSuchElementException.class and it worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to import `java.util.NoSuchElementException` instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is giving you a pretty good explanation.  You are providing an implementation of the `next()` method declared in [Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), which has a signature of:

```
public Object next()
```

However, you have introduced your own checked exception called `NoSuchElementException`, which required that you change the method signature to:

```
public Object next() throws NoSuchElementException
```

Now you are no longer implementing the method declared in the interface.  You've changed the signature.

Anyways, there are a couple ways you can fix this:

1. Change your `NoSuchElementException` class so that it inherits from [RuntimeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) instead of just `Exception`.  Then you don't need to add a `throws` declaration to the method signature.
2. Get rid of your custom exception type and instead use Java's built-in [NoSuchElementException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html), which already inherits from `RuntimeException`.  This is almost certainly the better option.

Answer (score 2):

The next() method of Iterator does not declare an exception to be thrown, so you can't decalre an exception if you are implementing it.

You can however throw an *unchecked* exception. The simple fix is to define your custom exception as `extends RuntimeException`, which will make it an unchecked exception.

I'm a little confused, because NoSuchElementException *is* an unchecked exception already, unless you have defined your own NoSuchElementException class.

Comment: hey thanks, i got it working by importing java.util.* and yes your solution also works !

Answer (score 1):

Check the javadocs for [java.util.Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and [java.util.NoSuchElementException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).  If you implement the Iterator interface, you have to play by its rules.  Import that exception; don't create it.